# Query field on contentversion from contentdoclink

Tags: soql

I had below SOQL to retrieve the records from content document link, created a new custom field "File_Type__c' on content version but not sure how to relate this field to my query:

```
SELECT 
      ContentDocumentId,
      ContentDocument.title, 
      ContentDocument.Description, 
      ContentDocumentId.ContentVersion.File_Type__c (***** Custom field on version)
FROM ContentDocumentLink WHERE LinkedEntityId ='1234'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to traverse a parent relationship from ContentDocument to ContentVersion. That relationship is called `LatestPublishedVersion`

```
SELECT 
      ContentDocumentId,
      ContentDocument.title, 
      ContentDocument.Description, 
      ContentDocumentId.LatestPublishedVersion.File_Type__c 
FROM ContentDocumentLink WHERE LinkedEntityId ='1234'
```

A good way to see relationship names is with Workbench or any other schema expolorer

[image]